# Scraping Federal Reserve Speeches calendar in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to scrape the Federal Reserve calendar for UPCOMING speeches. I have already successfully done so for the ECB, but the FED html seems to be a different beast. End goal is to have a dataframe with columns *date, time, board member, topic*.

To illustrate my problem I'll give an example of how I did it for ECB. 1) I made a list of next weeks' dates and matched them in a for loop with dates in the ECB website table (table=html code). 2) For each match I then pulled out the varibles of interest + did some formatting etc. not shown here.

I cannot figure out how I'd do something analogous to the FED html. It's mostly gibberish when you inspect and I think it's best illustrated with a picture

**code for scraping ECB**

```
for day in dates:
            #find the title of each entry in the date
           supertable=table.find_all("dt",text=day)
           # print(supertable)
           for i in range(len(supertable)):
                   #for each date-entry, find description
                   subtable=supertable[i].findNext("dd")
                   print(supertable[i])
                   print(subtable)
                   bm=subtable.find("span",class_="boardMember")
                   ti=subtable.find("span",class_="time")
                   ev=subtable.find("span",class_="event")
```

**html for ECB (example of specific date)**
*https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/calendars/weekly/html/index.en.html*

```
<div id="ecb-content-col" >
                    <main>
                        <h1>Weekly schedule of public speaking engagements and other activities</h1>
<h3>Friday, 17 July 2020 - Sunday, 26 July 2020</h3>
<dl class="ecb-basicList">
<dt >Monday, 20 Jul 2020</dt>
<dd>
<span class="event"><span class="label">Event:</span>Euro area monthly balance of payments (Dataset: BP6)</span>
<span class="time"><span class="label">Time:</span>10:00 CET</span>
<span class="infoWeb"><span class="label">Info website:</span><a class="arrow" href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/stats/bop/html/index.en.html" target="_self">https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/stats/bop/html/index.en.html</a></span>
<span class="lastModified">Last modified: 20 July 2020, 11:05 CET</span>
</dd>
<dt >Monday, 20 Jul 2020</dt>
<dd>
<span class="boardMember"><span class="label">Board member:</span>Luis de Guindos</span>
<span class="event"><span class="label">Event:</span>Participation by Mr de Guindos in the panel &quot;La respuesta europea frente a la crisis&quot; organised by Universidad Complutense de Madrid as part of the Cursos de verano de El Escorial</span>
<span class="time"><span class="label">Time:</span>10:00 CET</span>
<span class="venue"><span class="label">Venue:</span>Real Colegio Universitario Mar&iacute;a Cristina. Paseo de los Alamillos, 2, 28200 San Lorenzo de El Escorial, Madrid, Spain</span>
<span class="contact"><span class="label">Contact:</span>Esther Tejedor - ECB Global Media Relations - Tel: +49 69 1344 95596 - Mob: +49 172 5171280</span>
<span class="email"><span class="label">E-mail:</span><a class="mail" href="mailto:esther.tejedor@ecb.europa.eu">esther.tejedor@ecb.europa.eu</a></span>
<span class="infoWeb"><span class="label">Info website:</span><a class="external" href="www.pp.es" target="_blank">www.pp.es</a></span>
<span class="text"><span class="label">Text:</span>No text will be made available.</span>
<span class="notes"><span class="label">Notes:</span>The event will be streamed in Spanish via the above-mentioned link.</span>
<span class="lastModified">Last modified: 20 July 2020, 11:05 CET</span>
</dd>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                var currentContentsUrl = "/press/calendars/weekly/html/index_content.en.html";
                            </script>


                    </main>
                        
                </div>
```

**FED html**
*https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents.htm* (under "Calendar")

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fed calendar page is loaded dynamically using javascript, so it requires a different approach. Using the Developer tab in the browser you can see the link to the page that actually contains the data. Once you get that link and the request to that link, things are much simpler:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

cookies = {
    'BIGipServerwww.federalreserve.gov_hsts.app~www.federalreserve.gov_hsts_pool': '!XzbhBUzoOQRgHRNSiGDasURiAFpsPA28LjvywchJo0mMdcFUyd/2zqN601BqfWI2JmSmmNuETixO1A==',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/calendar.htm',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/calendar.json', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
cal = json.loads(response.text)
pd.DataFrame(cal['events'])
```

The output is the table you are looking for. You may have to clean it up a bit, drop irrelevant columns, etc., to get it to your expected final shape.